# Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am looking for solutions for push notifications in my android app, i have a php server and i have figured out a way to use GCM with php server, but can anyone help me with the client side code for implementing Google Cloud Messaging ?

Answer (score 4):

In the android sdk directory there are sample codes for the gcm-client and gcm-server. You can find that codes on the following directory. It is great for getting started.

> android-sdk/extras/google/gcm/samples

Comment: I don't see any php file in this folder. Are you sure about this ?

Comment: @DanChaltiel   In 2012 there was those sample codes but I am not sure about the new versions of the android sdk.